# How can I add the drag and drop support in the DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables, drag-and-drop

Is there a plugin which supports drag and drop of columns for `Datatable` without having any bugs
Looking forward for a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is everything in the web.

You can use jQuery UI. It's very easy to use. I suggest that you visit the official site of this library

https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I did what you said, but this is not responsive. What do I need to do for this